# Soundhound - Android - How to programmatically access Favorites ?

Tags: android, favorites

I understand that Soundhound on Android doesn't currently store favorites on the cloud. They must therefore be on the local storage somewhere. 
Does anyone know a good way to access the favorites programmatically ? 
I know the user can email his favorites but I would like to access them through my code without user interaction.

Thanks!

Comment: do I understand correctly that you want to access data of another app? Not possible (unless there is an API provided by the developer, or having root privileges) and not desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's discouraging to find a -1 vote on the first question I asked here but here's the answer to my own question anyways...
As of Android 4.2.2, the Soundhound data is stored in this Sqlite3 DB: 
/data/data/com.melodis.midomiMusicIdentifier.freemium/databases/bookmarks.db

There's no content provider for the bookmarks so of course using the DB isn't a good idea since its subject to change in any future release of the app.

Comment: As that's not your application's directory, you will need root to access the file as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Local app storage is generally restricted. One application can not access the local storage of another's without explicit permission of some sort. Either the application (Soundhound) has to set access to global (unlikely) or explicitly expose the data via some sort of API (also extremely unlikely). I would expect this to not be reasonably possible (without root permissions).